# SELECT WHERE conditon=met and condition=not-met, but there are related rows with condition=met (JOIN? UNION? Subquery?)

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get a result set with rows that meet certain conditions, but also includes rows that do not meet main conditions, but are linked to rows that do meet them. I know it may sound complex and unclear, so I've translated this quest into a simple example.

```
+--------------------------------+
| people                         |
+--------------------------------+
| ID  | Name | IsRich | ParentID |
+--------------------------------+
| 100 | John | 1      | NULL     |
| 101 | Tom  | 0      | NULL     |
| 102 | Kate | 0      | 101      |
| 103 | Bob  | 0      | 100      |
| 104 | Mike | 1      | 105      |
| 105 | Bill | 0      | NULL     |
+--------------------------------+
```

In this example, I want to select all *rich* people and people that are *not rich, but have a rich child*:

```
+---------------------+
| Desired result set  |
+---------------------+
| ID  | Name | IsRich |
+---------------------+
| 100 | John | 1      | -> because he is rich
| 104 | Mike | 1      | -> because he is rich
| 105 | Bill | 0      | -> because Mike is his child, and Mike is rich
+---------------------+
```

**What SQL can one use to get this result set?**

*Subquery, UNION, JOIN, some form of WHERE condition, something else?*

*Also, please help me rephrase the question title if you can..*

Comment: @GurV Although it's theoretically possible, my particular data set will not contain grandchild relations. But if it did, I would want every parent and grandparent included. For now I don't need to make SQL more complex than needed. Btw, I don't understand your second comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing selections should make you think `where`.  This is a typical way of expressing this:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.isRich = 1 or
      t.Id in (select t2.ParentId from t t2 where t2.isRich = 1)
```

Comment: the sql fiddle for this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/38da55/1  Seems to work, thought I'm not sure base on the question whether we want anyone who's rich _or_ has a rich child, or if isn't rich _and_ has a rich child.

Comment: @DanFarrell . . . I think it is clear that the OP intends `or`:  "select all rich people and people that are not rich, but have a rich child".

Answer (score 1):

A sub select, as mentioned by Gordon Linoff, works great. But, if you'd like to use a join (to pull additional data from the child, for example), here is another potential solution.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    -- look at all of the rows of people
    people parent
     -- tack on the child of each row
    LEFT JOIN people child ON child.ParentID = parent.ID
WHERE
    -- if either the child or the parent are rich, return the row
    (child.isRich = 1 || parent.isRich = 1)
```

Comment: this could create multiple rows with multiple children

Comment: Just a warning, child rows can get tricky in MySQL. MSSQL provides common table expressions that allow you to have a structure like your table (essentially a linked list) and do queries for rich children, grand children, great grand children, etc. If you need that functionality with MySQL, you may be better off doing the checks in code.

Comment: @Paparazzi, true. The OP didn't specify if the rows needed to be distinct or if every combination should be shown. If multiple rows for a parent isn't desired, a DISTINCT can be added to the query. (e.g. SELECT DISTINCT parent.* FROM ...)

Comment: Thank you guys. In my situation the uniqueness of the rows is guaranteed by the code architecture afterwards, but performance-wise it would be nice not to have duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

This is also possible with an UNION.

```
# SELECT all rich people (parent)
SELECT 
   people.id
 , people.Name
 , people.isRich
FROM 
 people
WHERE
 people.isRich = 1 

UNION ALL

# SELECT people (parent) with an rich child.
SELECT
   parent.ID
 , parent.Name
 , parent.isRich
FROM 
 people parent
INNER JOIN 
 people child 
ON
 parent.id = child.parentID
WHERE 
 child.isRich = 1
```

**result**

```
    id  Name    isRich  
------  ------  --------
   100  John           1
   104  Mike           1
   105  Bill           0
```

see demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eff447/2